# Why/how does angularjs `form` directive introduce scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[image]I have found `ng-if`, `ng-repeat` and `ng-controller` all introduce AngularJS scope (one with `$parent` method, id etc).

I am still unclear on directives like `form` and `ng-model`.

What are all the built-in angularJS directives that introduce scope?

Image attached showing form scope.

Comment: *"introduce scope"* is a very vague concept. Scope is the foundation for everything that gets rendered/watched in angularjs

Comment: but `form` directive uses neither of the three -> 
1) `scope: {...}` 
2) `scope: true` 3) `transclude: true`
So how does one know? @charlietfl @georgeawg